# Navbar background-color does not change

Tags: html, css

as posted on the title, I can't change the `background-color` of my navbar. But I'm sure that my external css is working.

HTML CODE:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}"><img src="{{logo.image.url}}" alt="no image provided" style="max-width: 10rem; max-height: 10rem;"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:register' %}">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cms' %}">Manage Web Content</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}" tabindex="-1">Admin Page</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      
        <ul class="sample">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">sample</a>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

EXTERNAL CSS:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: black;
}

.sample .nav-link {
    color: red;
}
```

And I will include a picture of my navbar just for reference. Take note of the `ul` tag with sample label in it, located at the right part of the navbar. It turned out to be red. That's how I knew the external CSS is working. Any ideas why is this happening?[image]

SOLUTION: thanks to those guys who answered in the comment section. And it seems that the problem is one of these classes `navbar-light` or`bg-light` , these are default classes from bootstrap framework. So, in order for my external css to work is I needed to put `!important` to override those 2 classes mentioned above:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: black !important;
}

.sample .nav-link {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Any other css overriding your external css? Try give `!important`.

Comment: `navbar-light` probably overrides it. Try `!important` or add a class at the end to override the css.

Comment: No, there's no css overriding my external css. Where should I put the `!important`?

Comment: `navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light` What are these? Is it a framework? Check the css of these classes, if they are defined by you.

Comment: @TusharShahi those tags are from bootstrap framework. I just copied a navbar template from getbootstrap.com

Comment: thanks for your answer, it seems that I am just missing the `!important` code in my css file for this to work.

Comment: it is not a good practice to use !important, in the CSS, just remove .navbar-light .bg-light from the nav tag and your code will run without adding !important in CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Remove `bg-light` bootstrap class from nav tag and add your custom class over their your result should be like this.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-example sticky-top"></nav>

.bg-example{
    background-color:orange;
}
```